# MEAN - Angular - JS - Extend server.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean.io

After a few days and weeks of programming an application based on MEAN, I got to the problem, that the usualy called server.js-file gets bigger and bigger.
It contains the application setup and configuration, also in there is the Angular-Routing and the Mongod-Queries. So you can imagine...

So my first question is, how to extand the file? For example, what do I need to do, that the Routing is in another file and also the queries are seperate and the application still finds the "way" to it.

Another topic but similar problem: The html-files are big and unclear to read, cause the Navbar (for example) is in each page, but has always the same code. So how would it be possible to inject that specific code into each html-page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your HTML file is getting large and difficult to manage and you are using the MEAN stack then you can write a new angular directive to help split up your html into smaller more manageable parts.

Write a new directive in angular for example.

`angular.directive('navbar', function(){
  return { 
    restrict: 'E'
    templateUrl: 'yourpath/navbar.html
  }`

Now in your html all you have to insert is the following:

`<navbar></navbar>`